How do I populate a ListBox with a list of results from an Async/Await process
I am trying to populate a listbox with the results from an HttpClient post request,  utilising the Async/await pattern.  The application is Excel VSTO.  The listbox resides in an Excel TaskPane.  I am getting this error message when I attempt to populate the listbox:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lbo1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
  Source=SpenHistorianClient
  StackTrace:
   at SpenHistorianClient.ucEvents.PopulateListBox() in C:\_VSSWorkArea\SPENHistorianClient\SpenHistorianClient\ucEvents.vb:line 410
   at SpenHistorianClient.ucEvents.VB$StateMachine_145_btnTagSearch_Click.MoveNext() in C:\_VSSWorkArea\SPENHistorianClient\SpenHistorianClient\ucEvents.vb:line 396

Here is the relevant code:
 Private Async Sub btnTagSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTagSearch.Click

      Dim filterText As String = Nothing
      Dim itemType As String = Nothing
      Dim cnt As Long


      Try

           _filteredItems = New TagDefinitions
           filterText = txtFilter.Text

           Await Globals.ThisAddIn.QueryTagList(Globals.ThisAddIn.WebServices(cboSource.SelectedIndex), _filterText, _itemType)

           _filteredItems = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetFilteredTagList(filterText)

           PopulateListBox()

      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try
 End Sub
 Public Sub PopulateListBox()

      Try
           For Each item In _filteredItems
                _activeLbo.Items.Add(item.TagName)
           Next

           'Now we have populated the listbox clear the collection as we have no further need of it at this time
           _filteredItems.Clear()

      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try

 End Sub

I wasn't expecting the cross-threading issue, because the class variable _filteredItems and the listbox are both defined in the TaskPane, which I understand to be the UI Thread, I have read a number of listbox cross-threading posts which talk about delegates and the use of a background worker however I am having difficulty transferring this knowledge to my particular context.

Any code executed asynchronously can be executed on a different thread, so you just treat your code the same as you would any other code that's executed on a thread other than the UI thread. Any examples that use Invoke or BeginInvoke with a delegate are applicable.

It is a little surprising to me; in the absence of ConfigureAwait I would have expected execution to resume on the UI thread.  Which version of .NET are you using?  This might vary between versions (and between Framework and Core/Core-derived).

Ok, so in the end I managed to work it out.  Ended up with the following solution:
 Private Async Sub btnTagSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTagSearch.Click

      Dim filterText As String = Nothing
      Dim itemType As String = Nothing
      Dim cnt As Long

      Try

           _filteredItems = New TagDefinitions
           filterText = txtFilter.Text

           Await Globals.ThisAddIn.QueryTagList(Globals.ThisAddIn.WebServices(cboSource.SelectedIndex), _filterText, _itemType)

           _filteredItems = Await Globals.ThisAddIn.GetFilteredTagList(filterText)
           Invoke(New PopulateListBoxHandler(
           AddressOf PopulateListBox))

      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try
 End Sub
 Private Delegate Sub PopulateListBoxHandler()
 Public Sub PopulateListBox()

      Try
           For Each item In _filteredItems
                _activeLbo.Items.Add(item.TagName)
           Next

           'Now we have populated the listbox clear the collection as we have no further need of it at this time
           _filteredItems.Clear()

      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try

 End Sub


I don't think you need the New PopulateListBoxHandler, I think it should be sufficient to use the result of AddressOf directly.
